# Send Multiples parameters angular controller to Asp .net MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to send 3 diferentes object from angular controller to Asp MVC controller using restangular, $http or resources, my objects are:

```
Employee ={Name:"Amy", Age:"17", Email:"Amy@test.com"};
User={UserName:"Amy17", Password:"test123"};
Role ={IdRole="11", Name:"User"}
```

and my method in asp mvc controller

```
Public void GetInfo(Employee _employee, User _user, Role _role)
{....}
```

I dont want to use a viewmodel, like:

```
Public Class VmGetInfo
{
Public Employee Employee {get; set;}
Public User User {get; set;}
Public Role Role {get; set;}
}
```

how i can do that using?

Comment: `I dont want to use a viewmodel, like`...any particular reason why you don't want to use that? Because that would definitely be right.

Comment: @ethorn10 rigth now i have around 100 classes, i dont want to create 200 or more vm classes for the view, is just a mess.

Comment: Is this a get method, or a post method?

Comment: Any reason you can't just send an object with those keys (_employee, _user, _role)?

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung, i try but does not work, just the first parameter got the data the other ones get null :s